# Add a feature to ban certain words in chatrooms

Tags: feature-request, chat

I just want to add this feature to let chatroom owners type certain words to ban them. For example some bad languages and stuff. Also, some chatrooms have their own rules, so chatroom owners should be able to change the list of words to ban.

Comment: Was this feature request triggered by something in particular?

Comment: @BSMP Just an idea we came up with in chat

Comment: What do you mean *"ban"*? Remove them when the message is posted? Reject the message entirely? Kick the user? What about the *"Scunthorpe problem"*? Finally, note that intent is more important than the word; if I call this a *"fracking stupid idea"* you may still get offended.

Comment: Chatroom owners being able to ban specific words. What could *possibly* go wrong? :)

Comment: A bad word filter never works. Just look how inventive spammers have become in getting certain topics past email filters (and how many are still getting past despite all of those efforts). Sorry, but this has been suggested before on the main Meta site, and was declined for the reasons that a) it really can't be done effecftively, and b) what you consider offensive someone else might not (or vice versa) - what if someone is offended by the word "darn" or "drat" or a certain phrasing? If you want to be able to censor content, you should probably do it on your own site where it's your decision.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this would be beneficial. Attempting to ban a word would just end up having slightly different versions of it being posted. Such as Question versus Questi0n, except with something offensive I would assume.

Furthermore, it doesn't properly solve the problem at hand. If a user is using vulgar language in a chat room and that room has specifically outlined not to use that type of language (not all rooms actually care about this by the way) then the user should have some sort of punitive action taken in response.

Either warn them, bin their message, kick-mute them, or use the "flag for moderator" and explain some sort of extreme abuse (not for average stuff, perhaps personal threats for example).

For more information on available tools to use see also: [How do I moderate my own chatroom?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300378/how-do-i-moderate-my-own-chatroom)