# Need a mentor for answer guidance

Tags: discussion

I am approaching three months now of general contribution here and have mostly been focusing on one "tag" in providing answers where I saw beforehand that the general answers were not of really good quality to serve the community as a whole, and have tried to provide better. Sometimes with success and sometimes not.

I don't think that I have done too bad in what is provided already, but I want to branch out into other tags and try to keep a reasonable standard in the answers that will be useful to others finding them.

Basic point: is there somewhere I can connect with other like-minded Stack Overflow users (apart from here) to share and more importantly "converse/mentor" on better ways to provide this in the future?

I know there are chat rooms, but a "network" is what I am really asking for. Is there a way that we can keep in touch in some sort of group? Some "formal/informal" program? Or any regular channel that people already use to keep in touch?

I would like a general "sounding board" on things such as:

- Good structure of answers for the topic
- Issues not typically addressed in topic answers

Maybe it is a regular chat room or something like that. Just asking from the perspective of someone who does not know and would like to be in touch with those who are active in making things better.

Comment: Many tags provide chatrooms, also there's _The Tavern_ chatroom, where everyone meets up.

Comment: Related, blog post by Jon Skeet: [Answering technical questions helpfully](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/)

Comment: @Oded That's really nice actually. But is there any "direct" channel for guidance? Which is what I am really asking and not general principles.

Comment: The sheer amount of your contributions in such a short time is rather impressive. Chatrooms can certainly help make you more discerning, to put it politely, but they also risk severely decreasing your answer proliferation.

Comment: Let me for completeness mention the [SO close vote reviewers room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) that has core group of regulars across tags that are active in moderation of questions and answers.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I wonder if "two words" means "in output" or "in markup"... Stack&nbsp;Overflow is probably wrong.

Answer (score 33):

Well, getting 10k reputation in 2 months sort of places you in very good company. It is very impressive. Moreover, you are doing this in a tag which does not have that much speed. Have you looked at your related activity in MongoDb? You are outpacing the all time leader in that tag at a rate of 6 to 1.

[image]

I would go so far as to say you could be at the forefront of this tag on Stack Overflow. So you need to create a structure that fits your needs and then allow other people to also share their input.

The chat system is best suited for the type of place you are looking for. However, *you* must create this place because it does not exist. Find a name for the room that best describes what it will be used for, choose a set of tags, and create the room.

The next step will be to begin building messages there or finding other like minded users who are actually willing to take part in the endeavor you envision. The best place to start that type of activity is here on meta. If you are going to do anything sweeping aside from posting content, such as retagging or editing (as in it will affect dozens of posts) then it is best to post here on meta first to get a feel for how the community views such a change (or to look to see if there was already a historical consensus on the topic).

So I would suggest that you do that for the mongo tag. As for branching into other tags, if you find a chat room for that tag then that is the best place to start. Most users in the tag rooms are well aware of the situation of that tag on Stack Overflow and often you will find very active contributors in that tag there who are also in touch with that community.

Chat here is very active, and the transcript stays public and searchable (as long as it stays active) for years and years. The first message sent to chat can still be found even though it happened many years ago.

tl;dr;

- Create a mongo chat room, you are clearly an expert
- Join a tag related chat room if you want to branch out to other topics

Here is some guidance on maintaining a chat room: [How do I moderate my own chatroom?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300378/how-do-i-moderate-my-own-chatroom/300395#300395)

Comment: You make fair points here, and it's not simple to "choose" an accepted response as I would expect people to do with general "answers". The one thing I do see is that "leaderboard" is peppered with users with little to no contribution in 5 years. And most of the contribution is basic syntax and usage rather than real explained solutions to problems. That is what I want to achieve, by really explaining the solution so it is understood and not just a correction. The general consensus seems to be "join a chat", which is perhaps what I asked. But it would be great to know "who is listening"

Comment: Comment too long. So perhaps I just need to find out.

Comment: @BlakesSeven - On meta comments aren't removed like they are on main so you can use multiple comments if you want. Can you expand on the "who is listening" part?

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear but the elaboration "was" essentially "perhaps I need to find out", as the "comment to long" was because I ran out of space in the preceeding comment and therefore wrote the next one. So it was more of a statement of "I wonder who I will meet" when particpating in such a chat in general. But thankyou again for the insight. Still don't know how to "pick an answer here" as both sides are equally complemtary to me. Dilemma.

Answer (score 24):

We have considered various forms of mentoring. One idea is to [use this very meta site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268779/can-we-make-this-meta-site-work-for-mentoring). Another is to build in a [new privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254205/opt-in-mentor-privilege-at-7-5k) that would allow experienced users to guide new users. But these ideas are geared toward users who have *no Stack Overflow experience*. As a 10k user, there's no reason you'd need that sort of mentoring.

As a rule, an answering style that works for one tag ought to work for others. Variations across tags largely stem from variations in the underlying technology and its tag. Perhaps the best way to learn how to answer is to read a bunch of other answers in the tag, find a question or two that you can address and post your own answer. That'll give people something more concrete to look at when you ask on meta. Chat is a great place to ask informally. Many of the most active tags have dedicated chat rooms and it's easy for users to [create a new chat room](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms) if needed. Finally, and importantly, people active in a tag often provide helpful comments on posted answers.

Comment: Normally a 10k user wouldn't need that sort of mentoring, but take note that OP has only been a member for *two months*. That's probably a severe deficit in "site mechanics exposure" compared to nearly all other 10k users.

Comment: This does seem consice, but I have a "slight addendum" though it was not in the question. There is a notable ["Warlords of documentation"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow?cb=1) post featured right now. I know the main tag I have been contributing to is "not on the first page of popular tags", but it is also in "dire need" of core documentation clarification as well as "driver documentation" and notably in the C# category. So if there was an "inroad" to being on the accepted list, then I would like to hear about it.