# Why does a welcome pop up appear upon entering the chat room?

Tags: support, chat

I am a chat room owner for two years, so I'm not quite new to chat. I just opened my browser and clicked on the tab on which I had opened my chat room.

I get shown a welcome pop up, which shouldn't happen, because I've obviously visited chat before:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what's going on ?

Comment: This behaviour has been observed multiple times today by users of [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).

Comment: I received this popup this morning as well, and also thought it was odd. Had to check to make sure i was logged in.

Comment: I dispute your assertion that you shouldn't see it just because you've been in chat before. I see long-time regulars behaving like total nincompoops in chat all the time. A reminder of the rules is not a bad thing!

Comment: "Keep these mind", was about to point out the mistake, went to a chat room, saw the pop-up, already fixed.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Over the past few months, we've been working on some new documentation for chat and some guidelines on how to make chat feel a bit less unmoderated. Today, we released this change aka the pop-up.

When a user enters chat for the first time, they will be presented with the pop-up reminding them that chat is an extension of the main site and we expect participants to abide by the [Be Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy.

Even if you were a regular chat user you got the pop-up because it was shown to all users who enter chat right after the feature was implemented. The pop-up is dismissible and shouldn't show up again.

## Related:

- [A guide to moderating chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat)
- [Toward a philosophy of Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270587/toward-a-philosophy-of-chat)

Comment: Do we have to dismiss it once? Or once for every chat room?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Should be once.

Comment: It appears to be "once for every SE site". So I have to click once for SO, another time for DBA.SE, once more for Mathematics, etc.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ chat.SO, chat.SE, and chat.math.SE?

Comment: @Braiam Yep....

Comment: It would be nice to extend this new feature to specific rooms as well.  I've made a [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276571) about it on Meta.SE.

Comment: Also related on MSO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300378/1026459

Comment: Excellent - chat needed this. Good job :)