# A Welcome Notification Bar gets displayed every time when opening chat

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, notifications

A Welcome Notification Bar gets displayed on the top every time I open chat, though I have opened it many times and I have 20 reputation also. It's quite annoying to see it again and again on the top. As mentioned in the comments, this post is different from [Why does a welcome pop up appear upon entering the chat room?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318468/why-does-a-welcome-pop-up-appear-upon-entering-the-chat-room) Following is the screenshot of the Notification Bar you might be knowing of:

[image: stackoverflow chat notification bar]

Comment: Until a few hours ago, you had less than 20 rep. It's entirely possible that chat doesn't recognize that you have more than 20 rep yet.

Comment: @Andy: Yes, that might be a possibility, thanks!

Comment: @ZAS I'm marking this as "by design" since the chat system (which is a separate system than the main site) takes a little bit of time to sync. with your actual rep on the main site (it's also the same between your meta user and main user accounts - as always - blame caching :p)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, at least not of the linked question.  Just look at the screenshots, it's two different notifications.